# Firebase interval combined query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have a firebase database structured like:

```
-users
    -[userID from the account]
        -[interval key generated automatically with push]
            -start: timestamp
            -end: timestamp
            -color: black
        -[interval key]
            -start: timestamp
            -end: timestamp
            -color: red
        -[interval key]
            -start: timestamp
            -end: timestamp
            -color: green
    -[userID2 from the account]
        -[interval key]
            -start: timestamp
            -end: timestamp
            -color: black
        -[interval key]
            -start: timestamp
            -end: timestamp
            -color: white
        -[interval key]
            -start: timestamp
            -end: timestamp
            -color: red
```

Using android i don't understand how to make some combined query.

If i have :

```
long start = 1494637200000;
long end =   1494640800000;
```

and:

```
DatabaseReference userRef = dbRef.child("users").child(uid);
```

If i can't use orderByChild() more then 1 time:

1)How can i get from the database all the intervals that are overlapping with the `start` and the `end` ?

Sql:

`select * 
from [userID] 
where start + " < " + 1494640800000 + " AND " + end + " > " + 1494637200000`

2)How can i get from the database all the intervals that are overlapping with the `start` and the `end`, but only with the color "`black`"?

Sql:

`select * 
from [userID] 
where start + " < " + 1494640800000 + " AND " + end + " > " + 1494637200000 AND color = "black"`

(I accept answers in different languages, just make it understandable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before starting to create those query i suggest you see this tutorial named: [The Firebase Database For SQL Developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s). You'll learn the exact way to achieve the exact thing you want.

To convert a value as mentioned below, please use this code:

```
String firebaseField = "1494637200000_1494640800000_black";
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

String[] data = firebaseField.split("_");
for(String part : data) {
    arrayList.add(part);
}

long start = Long.valueOf(arrayList.get(0));
long end = Long.valueOf(arrayList.get(1));
String color = arrayList.get(2);

if(yourStartValue < start && yourEndValue > end && color.equals("black")) {
    //Your logic here
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have already seen this tutorial before, the only method to query by 2-3 children it to combine them in one value separated by a special character. It's the only way ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. This is a common practice in Firebase.

Comment: If after a period of time, I want to query them by other 3 parameters, should I update all intervals with a new Value ? In your opinion it's more expensive to filter them one by one in every client ?

Comment: It's not a good option to query one by one, you need to query only once. As a suggestion, because Firebase is a NoSQL database, try to think to solve a problem not in terms of SQL. In Firebase, we don't use `SELECT` or `WHERE` clauses. Regarding your question, you can update but also you can create another interval with the specific query as needed.

Comment: Querying one time all items (intervals) and calling getValue() for every child (start,end,color) will do other queries by itself?

Comment: Definitely, query one time all intervals. And yes, use `getValue()` method to get the specific value for each child is neeeded. If you use this method, it doesn't mean you create additional queries, it means that you only get the data out from a the `dataSnapshot` object. That's all.

Comment: Let's say that i have the children start_end and start_end_color, how will be the queries then ( from my examples )? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Your field should look like this: `"start_end_color: "1494637200000_1494640800000_black"". Than you need to verify if your value is between the first two values and if the color is black.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think that will work in my case, I have to check if the intervals overlap ( not only if one is included in the other one ). I'am afraid that I have to take only a part (smaller) and then filter it into the client, or use it along a SQLite database.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help, you confirmed me that I have to filter it on the client side one by one. This will cost a lot on big data like 5000 items ( unfortunately I need all its children if the intervals overlap) . Thank you for your time.